# Always newest video on youtube

Tags: javascript, html, video, youtube

is there any possible way, to have on website always newest youtube video from specific channel? Like when i upload new video, it will automaticaly jump to new video.

Answer (score 0):

1. Get the id of your *upload playlist* within this link: [Google Developer API Page](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/youtube/v3/youtube.channels.list) (part=contentDetails and forUsername=[YOUR_USERNAME])
2. Get the JSON data with this API: [Google Developer API Page](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/youtube/v3/youtube.playlistItems.list) (playlistID=[YOUR_UPLOAD_PLAYLIST_ID] and maxResults=1 (for the newest video))

Google uploaded a video of this topic: [YouTube Developers Live: Getting a Channel's Uploads in v3](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RjUlmco7v2M)